# Error in filtering Sql returns direct cast error

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

Hi I have my function that is using Entity Frameworks to get data and then based on additional parameters with do additional filtering.

This is my Function:

```
Public Shared Function GetSstCodeComboList(ByVal fCustomerID As Integer,
                                                   ByVal fEventType As String,
                                                   ByVal fSpringCode As String,
                                                   ByVal fActive As Boolean) As List(Of SstCodeComboList)

Dim sstList = New List(Of SstCodeComboList)

Dim de = New SchedulerEntitiesConn()

Dim sstQuery As IQueryable(Of SstCodeComboList) = Nothing

Try
    'CustomerID 0 is Generic.
    If fCustomerID > 0 Then
        'We have a specific Customer. Get all Customer Codes.
        sstQuery = (From c In de.vw_SSTCodes
                    Where c.sstCustomerFk = fCustomerID And c.sstID > 4
                    Order By c.sstDetail
                    Select New SstCodeComboList With {.sstID = c.sstID,
                                    .sstDetail = c.sstDetail,
                                    .sstProjectCode = c.sstProjectCode,
                                    .sstProjectName = c.sstProjectName,
                                    .sstTaskNo = c.sstTaskNo,
                                    .sstTaskName = c.sstTaskName,
                                    .sstCustomer = c.Customer,
                                    .sstRU = c.sstRU,
                                    .sstRedundant = c.sstRedundant})


        'Now filter the list down where necessary
        If Not IsNothing(sstQuery) Then

            If fActive Then
                'We only need active codes so filter down to where Redundant = False
                sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) f.sstRedundant = False)
            End If

            'Do filtering on Spring Codes if setting is set to true and the param fSpringCode is not null or empty
            If Settings.Default.filterSpringCodes = True And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fSpringCode) Then
                'Filtering on Spring Codes
                'First check first char - if ! then we need all codes that are NOT spring codes
                'i.e. do not begin with the rest of fSpringCode value
                If Left(fSpringCode, 1) = "!" Then
                    Dim filter As String = fSpringCode.Replace("!", "")
                    sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) Left(f.sstTaskNo, 3) <> filter) '#####THIS WORKS
                Else
                    'we have one or more spring codes
                    'create array from fSpringCode
                    Dim sCodeArray() As String = Split(fSpringCode, ",")
                    'find out how many codes we have (MAX is 3)
                    Dim sCodeCount = sCodeArray.Length
                    
                    '##### THE FILTERS BELOW DON'T WORK
                    'get error DirectCast(sstQuery, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery(Of Scheduler.Models.SstCodeModel.SstCodeComboList)).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
                    Select Case (sCodeCount)
                        Case 1
                            'sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) LEFT(f.sstTaskNo, 5) = sCodeArray(0))
                            'sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(0))                                        
                            'sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) LEFT(f.sstTaskNo, 5) = sCodeArray(0).ToString)
                            sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(0).ToString))
                        Case 2
                            sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(0).ToString) Or f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(1).ToString))
                        Case 3
                            sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(0).ToString) Or f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(1).ToString) Or f.sstTaskNo.StartsWith(sCodeArray(2).ToString))
                    End Select

                        'If there were more than 3 spring codes then no filtering will be done.
                    
                End If

            End If
            'Transfere each SSTCode left in query to sstList.
            For Each s In sstQuery
                sstList.Add(New SstCodeComboList() With {.sstID = s.sstID,
                            .sstDetail = s.sstDetail,
                            .sstProjectCode = s.sstProjectCode,
                            .sstProjectName = s.sstProjectName,
                            .sstTaskNo = s.sstTaskNo,
                            .sstTaskName = s.sstTaskName,
                            .sstRU = IIf((s.sstRU = "U"), "Unrecoverable", IIf((s.sstRU = "RBAU"), "BAU UT", IIf((s.sstRU = "RPROJECT"), "Project", "-"))),
                            .sstClass = IIf((s.sstRU = "U"), "btn-danger", IIf((s.sstRU = "RBAU"), "btn-success", IIf((s.sstRU = "RPROJECT"), "btn-warning", "btn-info"))),
                            .sstCustomer = s.sstCustomer})
            Next

        End If

    End If
    'clear query
    sstQuery = Nothing

    'Now get all Generic customer sstcodes
    sstQuery = (From c In de.vw_SSTCodes
                Where c.sstCustomerFk = 0 And c.sstID > 4
                Order By c.sstDetail
                Select New SstCodeComboList With {.sstID = c.sstID,
                                    .sstDetail = c.sstDetail,
                                    .sstProjectCode = c.sstProjectCode,
                                    .sstProjectName = c.sstProjectName,
                                    .sstTaskNo = c.sstTaskNo,
                                    .sstTaskName = c.sstTaskName,
                                    .sstCustomer = c.Customer,
                                    .sstRU = c.sstRU,
                                    .sstRedundant = c.sstRedundant})


    'Now add all GENERIC customer sst code from query to list
    If Not IsNothing(sstQuery) Then

        For Each s In sstQuery
            sstList.Add(New SstCodeComboList() With {.sstID = s.sstID,
                        .sstDetail = s.sstDetail,
                        .sstProjectCode = s.sstProjectCode,
                        .sstProjectName = s.sstProjectName,
                        .sstTaskNo = s.sstTaskNo,
                        .sstTaskName = s.sstTaskName,
                        .sstRU = IIf((s.sstRU = "U"), "Unrecoverable", IIf((s.sstRU = "RBAU"), "BAU UT", IIf((s.sstRU = "RPROJECT"), "Project", "-"))),
                            .sstClass = IIf((s.sstRU = "U"), "btn-danger", IIf((s.sstRU = "RBAU"), "btn-success", IIf((s.sstRU = "btn-warning"), "Project", "btn-info"))),
                        .sstCustomer = s.sstCustomer})
        Next
    End If


Catch ex As Exception

    sstList.Add(New SstCodeComboList() With {.sstID = 0, .sstDetail = ex.Message})

    Helpers.Helpers.LogException("GetSstCodeComboList", "SstCodeComboList", ex)

Finally

    de.Dispose()

End Try


Return sstList
```

End Function

Typical values for fSpringCode are:

- Empty String = No additional filtering required
- !ADS = We filter out any codes that start with ABS
- ADS01 = We filter down to any codes that = ADSO1
- ADS01,ADS04,ADS13 = We filter down so we are left with any codes that start with any of the 3 values passed.

!ABS as a filter works.
All the others do not. I get the error:
DirectCast(sstQuery, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery(Of Scheduler.Models.SstCodeModel.SstCodeComboList)).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

If you look at the Select Case code... in Case 1 I have various variations on the filter I have tried... all 4 variations give the same error.

Any help appreciated.. or a different approach considered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was with the array sCodeArray. Linq does not like array indexes and so I have had to change the code so that I don't use arrays. This explained why the !ABS value worked as I was using a string variable in the Linq.

So in a nutshell:

```
var filter = "ABS";
var filterArray = ["ABS03", "ABS07", "ABS13"];

sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) Left(f.sstTaskNo, 3) <> filter); 'THIS WORKS
sstQuery = sstQuery.Where(Function(f) Left(f.sstTaskNo, 5) = filterArray(0)); 'THIS DOES NOT
```